# Convert dateTime to ISO format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a standard way in .NET/C# to convert a datetime object to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=ISO_8601) format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss?

Or do I need to do some string manipulation to get the date string?

Comment: This is not ISO format. you're missing the `T` ( and optionally - time zone)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There is no standard format for the readable 8601 format. You can use a custom format:

```
theDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss")
```

(The standard format "s" will give you a "T" between the date and the time, not a space.)

Comment: Note that this will use `/` as date separator in places like the US and France (as in `2009/12/16 08:42:16`)

Comment: @Fredrik: No, it won't. If I would have used / in the format then it would have use the culture specific date separator, but - is a literal character and won't be replaced by anything else.

Comment: @Guffa: you are right, of course. Mixed it up, my bad.

Comment: Nice one Guffa, I appreciate the help.

Comment: What about "u" nowadays? See DateTimeFormatInfo.UniversalSortableDateTimePattern Property

Comment: @johv Apparently it adds a "Z" at the end too, to show that it's UTC.

Comment: @johv: Yes, and interrestingly it does that even if the `DateTime` value isn't UTC....

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: This is incorrect. The standard requires a T when combining date and time. It can only be omitted when both parties agree. Using this directly with a browser will fail, for instance. Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations

Answer (score 80):

To use the strict `ISO8601`, you can use the `s` ([Sortable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Sortable)) format string:

```
 myDate.ToString("s"); // example 2009-06-15T13:45:30
```

It's a short-hand to this custom format string:

```
myDate.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss");
```

And of course, you can build your own custom format strings.

More info:

- [Standard Date and Time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)
- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: This should be the accepted solution.

Answer (score 17):

To add a little bit more information that confused me;
I had always thought the same result could be achieved like so;

```
theDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

However, If your Current Culture doesn't use a colon(:) as the hour separator, and instead uses a full-stop(.) it could return as follow:

> 2009-06-15 13.45.30

Just wanted to add why the answer provided needs to be as it is;

```
theDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss")
```

:-)

Comment: This worked perfectly converting a C# DateTime to a SQLServer smalldatetime. The strings were accepted in the insert statement.

Comment: This is not ISO8601. 'T' must separate Date and time.

Comment: They are continuously giving me the error conversion.

Answer (score 10):

```
date.ToString("o") // The Round-trip ("O", "o") Format Specifier
date.ToString("s") // The Sortable ("s") Format Specifier, conforming to ISO86801
```

[MSDN Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The DateTime::ToString() method has a string formatter that can be used to output datetime in any required format. See *[DateTime.ToString Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326721(VS.71).aspx)* for more information.

Comment: myDate.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss");
 - does not work for me.  Maybe try String.Format() ?

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using this format all the timme like me I did an extension method.
I just wanted to share because I think it can be usefull to you.

```
     /// <summary>
    /// Convert a date to a human readable ISO datetime format. ie. 2012-12-12 23:01:12
    /// this method must be put in a static class. This will appear as an available function
    /// on every datetime objects if your static class namespace is declared.
    /// </summary>
    public static string ToIsoReadable(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss");
    }
```