# ASP.NET Server-side datetime problem

Tags: asp.net, datetime

I came across an issue that I'm not sure how to resolve. I developed a web application which makes use of DateTime.UtcNow. After testing on my local machine and everything worked fine, I deployed the application to the server. The server is flipping the month and day, so instead of it being August 10th, it says it is October 8th. This must be a regional thing, but I don't want to force a specific format. What's the best solution for this?

EDIT: I think it might be because I'm converting the datetimes into strings. How should I represent them as a string depending on the machine?

Comment: So its outputting like 8/10 intead of 10/8? I think in some regions thats the expected format.

Comment: Sorry but what's the issue then if you don't want to force a specific format.

Comment: See here: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-date-format

Comment: The issue is that I need a string which can be valid in all regions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When displaying the `DateTime`, format it with a specific culture.

```
myDateTime.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
myDateTime.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
myDateTime.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

I also suggest reading up on [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) date and time format strings.

Comment: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture: will this give the right time in all regions then?

Comment: @Jon - It stands for "no culture" and is based on `en-US`. So, in the UK it will not be correct.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. So what would happen if a user passed in a US time to the server, which is in Canada?

Comment: @Jon - If you format the `DateTime` using `InvariantCulture`, it will show up the same way _everywhere_.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ISO-Fromat for reading and saving dates

have a look at the below:

[Convert dateTime to ISO format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912894/c-convert-datetime-to-iso-format-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss)

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN has a really good example:

```
using System;

public class DateToStringExample
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      DateTime dateValue = new DateTime(2008, 6, 15, 21, 15, 07);
      // Create an array of standard format strings.
      string[] standardFmts = {"d", "D", "f", "F", "g", "G", "m", "o", 
                               "R", "s", "t", "T", "u", "U", "y"};
      // Output date and time using each standard format string.
      foreach (string standardFmt in standardFmts)
         Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", standardFmt, 
                           dateValue.ToString(standardFmt));
      Console.WriteLine();

      // Create an array of some custom format strings.
      string[] customFmts = {"h:mm:ss.ff t", "d MMM yyyy", "HH:mm:ss.f", 
                             "dd MMM HH:mm:ss", @"\Mon\t\h\: M", "HH:mm:ss.ffffzzz" };
      // Output date and time using each custom format string.
      foreach (string customFmt in customFmts)
         Console.WriteLine("'{0}': {1}", customFmt,
                           dateValue.ToString(customFmt));
   }
}
// This example displays the following output to the console:
//       d: 6/15/2008
//       D: Sunday, June 15, 2008
//       f: Sunday, June 15, 2008 9:15 PM
//       F: Sunday, June 15, 2008 9:15:07 PM
//       g: 6/15/2008 9:15 PM
//       G: 6/15/2008 9:15:07 PM
//       m: June 15
//       o: 2008-06-15T21:15:07.0000000
//       R: Sun, 15 Jun 2008 21:15:07 GMT
//       s: 2008-06-15T21:15:07
//       t: 9:15 PM
//       T: 9:15:07 PM
//       u: 2008-06-15 21:15:07Z
//       U: Monday, June 16, 2008 4:15:07 AM
//       y: June, 2008
//       
//       'h:mm:ss.ff t': 9:15:07.00 P
//       'd MMM yyyy': 15 Jun 2008
//       'HH:mm:ss.f': 21:15:07.0
//       'dd MMM HH:mm:ss': 15 Jun 21:15:07
//       '\Mon\t\h\: M': Month: 6
//       'HH:mm:ss.ffffzzz': 21:15:07.0000-07:00
```

You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx)