# DateTime across any culture

Tags: c#, datetime, cultureinfo

I'm trying to pass a DateTime object to my webservice. The system keeps telling me that there's an SqlDateOverflow error. I've tried converting the object to a string but the same error persists.

How can I pass a DateTime object from a system that uses a certain culture, and the server on which the webservice resides uses a different culture? Is there any way to standardize the object so that any system, regardless of its culture, can parse the object to its DateTime equivalent?

I have tried using the DateTime.Parse method, the DateTime.TryParse method, and even the DateTime.ParseExact method but all of them result in 'SqlDateOverflow'.

Comment: What is the date you are trying to pass through? Does it **fit** into a SQL `DATETIME` (January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999)?

Comment: If you want to be culture independent use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Answer (score 0):

I would always pass dates as strings in `ISO8601` format

See 
[Convert dateTime to ISO format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912894/c-sharp-convert-datetime-to-iso-format-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this problem you could modify the SQL script / procedure you call in your webservice, addin at the start this:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy; -- day/month/year
```

or

```
SET DATEFORMAT mdy; -- month/day/year
```

This way, if you pass it as a string correctly formatted, your SQL engine will always treat it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details as far as what culture you are going to/from, this may help your issue at hand

```
DateTime.Parse(yourDateTimeString,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```